# TcpClient not sending message

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcpclient

I have got problem sending data with C# TcpClient.

This is how my code looks like:

```
        public Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 7171);
            writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            client.Client.NoDelay = true;
            client.NoDelay = true;

            sendFirstPacket();
            while (true)
            {
                if (client.GetStream().DataAvailable)
                    Logger.log(Log_Type.ERROR, "mam cos");

            }
            Logger.log(Log_Type.INFO, "Spoko luz");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log(Log_Type.ERROR, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //client.Close();
        }
    }

    void onSendDone()
    {
    }

    void sendFirstPacket()
    {
        writer.Write((byte)10);
        writer.Write((ushort)2);
        writer.Write((ushort)854);
        UInt32[] k = new UInt32[4];

        k[0] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[1] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[2] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[3] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;

        writer.Write((byte)0); // first byte have to be 0
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[0]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[1]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[2]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[3]);
        writer.Flush();
        //client.GetStream().Write(
    }
```

Unfortunetly, after few seconds i have got "i/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" on my server (written in C++).
But if i change this code, and put sendFirstPakcet() into while loop, it will send packet correct (i count over 700 loops), then exception throw: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
 public Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 7171);
            writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            client.Client.NoDelay = true;
            client.NoDelay = true;

            sendFirstPacket();
            while (true)
            {
                if (client.GetStream().DataAvailable)
                    Logger.log(Log_Type.ERROR, "mam cos");

                sendFirstPacket();
            }
            Logger.log(Log_Type.INFO, "Spoko luz");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log(Log_Type.ERROR, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //client.Close();
        }
    }

    void onSendDone()
    {
    }

    void sendFirstPacket()
    {
        writer.Write((byte)10);
        writer.Write((ushort)2);
        writer.Write((ushort)854);
        UInt32[] k = new UInt32[4];

        k[0] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[1] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[2] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;
        k[3] = (12444 << 16) | 12444;

        writer.Write((byte)0); // first byte have to be 0
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[0]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[1]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[2]);
        writer.Write((UInt32)k[3]);
        writer.Flush();
        //client.GetStream().Write(
    }
```

What can be a reason of that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a problem on the server side. For example, you may be trying to read more bytes than you are sending, which would appear to be "fixed" if you sending many messages rapidly.